# Developing custom editable grid in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am quite new to MS Dynamics CRM, and I am working with 2011 on-prem version. I have a requirement where I have to use the in-line editable grid to update the data at one shot. But with some research and try, I figured out that it is not possible as "Out of Box" feature.

I tried finding code related to customized editable grid that can be used in CRM, but most of the time I ended up having a 3rd party control to be consumed. But I would like to understand and if possible build the code for the custom grid control for achieving the editable grid.

One approach could be developing a control out side the CRM and then adding it as addin and consume it. I have some thoughts but did not land up in any proper solution.

Is there anyone who can help me out in understanding/developing the custom grid control myself without using 3rd Party tools?

Thanks,
Ashfaq.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using silverlight or with jquery with HTML.